# How to add one more column to my file (modifiedFlights.csv) from another file (original.csv)

Tags: python

I want to add one `names` column in my file (`modifiedFlights.csv`) from another file (`original.csv`) which has a column `names`. The goal is to add names in `modifiedFlights.csv` after comparing column `hashes` which is present in both files. But I am not able to do so.

```
import os
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import pandas
import csv
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import sys, argparse, csv

hashes=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\original.csv', usecols=[0]) #hashes in original.csv
names=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\original.csv', usecols=[1])
this=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\csv files\modifiedFlights.csv', usecols=[4])# hashes in modifiedFlights.csv

for i in hashes:
    for y in this:
        if i == y:
            results_row=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\original.csv', usecols=[1], userows=[i])
            with open(r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\csv files\modifiedFlights.csv','r') as csvinput:
                with open(r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\out.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
                    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
                    for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
                        writer.writerow(row+[result_row])
```

Comment: Heard of `pd.merge()`? This could lead you to a solution.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples to improve your question

Comment: I guess what you need was called "left join" or "join". It is a basic operation of dataframe work. You probably could directly find a function from whatever package you were using by searching in the manual.